# ViewModel with Asynchronous Data Load and SavedStateHandle

Tags: android, android-livedata, android-architecture-components, android-viewmodel

I'm new to `ViewModel` and am trying to figure out what the best practices are for using `SavedStateHandle` in tandem with asynchronously loading data from an API.

My use case is that my `ViewModel` data should be loaded in once from the API, and after that I want the `SavedStateHandle` to save that data so if I come back to the fragment it doesn't perform that API call again. I only want that data refreshed from the API on a pull down to refresh mechanism in the UI, otherwise it should use the `SavedStateHandle` data.

I've found plenty of examples using one or the other (asynchronous data load or `SavedStateHandle` but not both.

Here is my initial code that does not use `SavedStateHandle`

```
class FilmsViewModel(private val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle): ViewModel() {
    private val filmsLiveData : MutableLiveData<List<Film>?> by lazy {
        MutableLiveData<List<Film>?>().also {
            loadFilms()
        }
    }

    fun getFilms(): LiveData<List<Film>?> {
        return filmsLiveData
    }

    fun loadFilms() {
        Log.d("FilmsViewModel", "loadFilms")
        StarWarsApiService.getFilms(object: FilmsCallback {
            override fun success(films: List<Film>?) {
                filmsLiveData.value = films
            }
        }, object: ErrorCallback {
            override fun error(error: ApiError) {
                // TODO
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: And how you "back to the fragment"? What is stopping you from checking if SavedStateHandle contains given data if not the load it from API?... I bet that SavedStateHandle is not what you think it is...

Comment: @Selvin that's exactly where I am confused. Where do I perform that check on if the data SavedStateHandle contains the given data

Comment: You may do this in `also` and put value in `success`...

Answer (score 1):

By default, the way Google intended (and which DOES try to re-fetch in onStart) you would make `StarWarsApiService.getFilms` be `suspend fun` instead of callback-based, then you can do

```
class FilmsViewModel(private val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle): ViewModel() {
    val filmsLiveData = liveData {
        emit(loadFilms())
    }
}
```

But what you're looking for is a regular `viewModelScope.launch {` that saves the retrieved data in a `MutableLiveData`, OR into local storage (Room) that would expose a `LiveData<List<T>>` which would be observed by the Fragment.

SavedStateHandle isn't for data, it is for state.